# Subject with -ian suffix is a?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology, vocabulary, suffixes

Is there a word which describes the relation of, when associating or committing, an added suffix such as “-ian” (or “-ic”, et al.) to its subject?

For example:

“Orwellian is the _____ of/for Orwell.”

Or:

John: I know what ‘encyclopedia’ means, but what does ‘encyclopedic’ mean?

Doe: Encyclopedic is just the ________ of/for ‘encyclopedia’.

Comment: *Cartesian is the [**adjectival form**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+the+adjectival+form%22) of Descartes*. Some of them are a bit tricky - ***Shavian*** = for *relating to [G.B.] **Shaw***, for example. I'd use ***of*** after ***form*** there, but maybe *Homeric is the adjective **for** Homer* would be a reasonable preposition usage.

Comment: From [the full OED:](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2427?rskey=bFt8iK&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) ***adjective*** (verb) - *To use as an adjective; to change or form into an adjective; = **adjectivize,** verb.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting, ty. You’re suggesting the word I’m looking for is **adjective/al form** [or not and hence only a comment]? Initially didn’t strike me precise enough. Maybe it’s actually that simple.

Comment: I can't see any other term being "more precise" than **adjective/al form** for the general case. But there would also be the possibility of, for example, [*"Quickly" is the **adverbial** form of "quick".*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22quickly+is+the%22+%22of+quick%22)